# Propositional logic - entailment

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given 3 formulas A,B,C , which answer is correct:

a) $(A  \models (B \Rightarrow C) ) \Leftrightarrow ((A \Rightarrow  B) \models C)$

b) $(A  \models (B \Rightarrow C) ) \Leftrightarrow (A \models C)$

I tried to rewrite $\models$ by $\Rightarrow$ and make truth tables , but I have not found anything in that tables what could help me solve this.

Comment: Nothing is correct. Could you state the reason why?

Comment: Comparing the [truth tables](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+implies+b,a+implies+(b+implies+c),(a+implies+b)+implies+c,a+implies+c) of $a\to (b\to c)$ and $(a\to b)\to c$ *should* be somewhat helpful.  I'd also include a column for $a\to b$ and $a\to c$